# Nothing else but package.json will load

Tags: reactjs

When starting a react app with npx create-react-app app-name, nothing else but package.json and node modules will install. I pasted the two photos bellow, i don't understand why it doesnt create the webpack and babel files aswell as the src file. Thanks in advance.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XziE1.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o0Ri.png

Comment: You didnt add any picture.

Comment: the links are it.

Comment: you sure you are in `/simpleapp/my-app` directory and not in `/simpleapp`?

Comment: for babel and webpack files you have to do it manually yourself and some configuration in package.json.

Comment: as far as i know, src file and everything else, the whole base template should load with the npx create-react-app command